# $P(X>16|X>10)$ - normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

If $X$ is a normal random variable with parameters mean = 10 and  standard deviation= 6, compute
$P(X>16|X>10)$ ?

Can someone help to explain this $P(X>16|X>10)$ in the normal rv. term? How do we graph this $P(X>16|X>10)$ ?

Thanks

Sean

Comment: Is the question about what the $P(\cdot|\cdot)$ notation means or how to find the value in this case?

Comment: Sure the variance is not 36?

Comment: Too bad-- variance 36 (hence std 6) makes for nicer formulas.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**.  Start with the usual conditional probability formula,
$$P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}\ .$$
In this case $A\subseteq B$, so $A\cap B=A$.  See if you can finish the calculation from here.

Answer (score 2):

$P[X>16\vert X>10]$ is the proportion of that part of the probability mass of $X$ which is above $10$ which is also above $16$.

Draw the pdf of $X$.  Lightly shade that part which is above $10$ (this is the right hand part of the distribution).  Now, heavily shade the part which is above $16$.  The conditional probability is the proportion of the lightly shaded region which is also heavily shaded.  You calculate this by taking the heavily shaded area ($P[X>16]$) and dividing (or *normalizing*) by the lightly shaded area ($P[X>10]$):
$$P[X>16 \vert \, X>10] = \frac{P[X>16]}{P[X>10]}$$

(Note that the general form of a conditional probability would require the numerator of this expression to be $P[X>16 \textrm{ and } X>10]$, but since $X>16\Rightarrow X>10$, this just reduces to $P[X>16]$.)

Comment: Thanks -P(X>10) = Phi(0) = .5
P(X>16) = 1-Phi(1) = 1-.8413 = .1587
P(X > 16|X > 10) = .1587/.5 = .3175

Comment: Be careful - the question states that it is the variance that is 6, not the standard deviation.

Comment: $\sigma=\sqrt{6} $, unless there was a typo in the question.